# HTML links show up but don't work properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am relatively new to javascript and creating servers/websites so sorry if there is something very stupid :)
When I go to the server address it displays all the links but I cant click them. I can right click it, copy the link address and search it and that works but I cant find any issue with my code. There is no CSS file
This is my all my code:

```
/*
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
<<<<<<<<<<<<< Below created by J.E >>>>>>>>>>>>>
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
*/

/* requires */
var fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https')
const http = require("http");

/*----------------------
 setting up the server 
 ----------------------*/
const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8080;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var html = buildHtml(req);

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Content-Length': html.length
  });
  res.end(html);
}).listen(port);

console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);

/*--------------------
  Setting up the logs
--------------------*/
let logdirname = "G:/logs/";

let all_logs = fs.readdirSync(logdirname, function(err, filenames){
    if(err){
        onError(err);
        return;
    }
});

let i = 0;
let log_array = []; // create array to add log name into
let link = "<table>";

all_logs.forEach((log_) => {
  log_array[i] = "Log File " + i;
  link += `<tr><td><a href="file:///G:/NodeOctaveService/logs/${(log_)}">${log_array[i]}</a></td></tr>\n`;
  i++;
})

link += "</tables>";

/*------------------------
  Setting up the HTML file
------------------------*/

function buildHtml(req){

  // html header
  var header = `
  <title>Octave Service Links</title>

<h1> Click the link to the log file you want to open. </h1>

<style>
      *,
      html{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 10;
          border-color: blueviolet;
      }

      html{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
      }

      body{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: relative;
          background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;
      }

      .center{
          width: 100%;
          height: 50%;
          margin: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          color:darkgreen;
          font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
          text-align: center;
      }

      h1{
      font-size: 80px;
      color: blueviolet;
      }
      </style>
      `;

      // html file body
  var body = ` ${link} `;

  return "<!DOCTYPE html>" + "<html><head>" + header + "</head><body>" + body + "</body></html>";
}
```

Comment: Your links are prefixed with `file://` meaning that they reference some path on disk. Your browser has no access to the rest of your filesystem and as such nothing happens when you click on them.

Comment: the links are to a file on my PC, is it therefore not possible for the links to work due to the browser not having access to them?

Comment: bool3max is right, also add target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" in the anchor tag to open the URL in new tab and rel is used for security. reference - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-html-to-open-link-in-new-tab/#:~:text=Security%20concerns%20with%20target%3D%22_blank%22

Comment: @James_Calvert Yes, you would need to make your HTTP server serve those files over the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add HTML download attribute in your  tag

```
all_logs.forEach((log_) => {
  log_array[i] = "Log File " + i;
  link += `<tr><td><a href="/your_link/logs/${(log_)}" download>${log_array[i]}</a></td></tr>\n`;
  i++;
})
```